# how to store results from nested loops in R

Tags: r, loops, nested-loops

I am new to using r and I need some help.
I have a data frame 'called price data' (xts) that consists of 28 stocks (as rows) and prices in different dates.
I want to apply the below formula (summing the squared difference of stock prices ) and store the result which should be 28*28=784. I am trying to store them in a vector but gives me zeros.

```
storage<-vector("numeric",784)
for (i in 1:784){
  for(j in 1:28){
    for (k in 1:28){
      storage[i]<-sum(((pricedata[,j]-pricedata[,k])^2))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typical R approach would be to use the `apply` family of functions.  Here's a proposal:

**Create a table of permutations.**

```
loopindex <- expand.grid(j = 1:28, k = 1:28)
```

**Use apply, by row.**

```
list.storage <-apply(loopindex , 1, function(x) {
                           sum(pricedata[, x[["j"]]] - pricedata[, x[["k"]]]) ^ 2 })
```

**Transform your list to a data frame**

```
df<-do.call("rbind", list.storage)
```